# Did the "Shuumatsu Nani Shitemasu ka?" anime cut content from the novels?

Tags: worldend

As not so long ago the anime adaptation of the **Shuumatsu Nani Shitemasu ka? Isogashii desu ka? Sukutte Moratte Ii desu ka?** novel ended we were left with quite an open ending

My questions are the following: did the anime left some important content out (its normal to skip some as it can't be all adapted) and if so, how much? Furthermore, if I plan to read the novels, should I start from the beginning (if the anime skipped some parts) or start where the anime ended (if you could provide that information too I'd be very grateful)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B5%82%E6%9C%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B%3F_%E5%BF%99%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B%3F_%E6%95%91%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B%3F#.E3.83.86.E3.83.AC.E3.83.93.E3.82.A2.E3.83.8B.E3.83.A1), the anime partly covers up to the 3rd volume of the light novel.

[AniComiMan (Japanese)](http://anicomi-man.com/shumatsu-1kan-netabare-10781), a blog that provides spoiler for the light novel prefaced it with

> Those who want to know the part that was not included in the anime, because in my opinion there is a big difference, it'd be good to read the original light novel.

---

A review by [Inquisitr](http://www.inquisitr.com/4317753/world-end-season-2-light-novel-sukasuka-sukamoka-spoilers-movie-worldend-what-do-ou-do-at-the-end-of-the-world/) (**warning: the site included speculation to season 2's material**) stated,

> Overall, the anime adaptation of the *Suka Suka* light novel is good and does not sacrifice pacing, although various scenes were rearranged and shortened. Anime usually has to skim over certain details and world building is discarded to fit the source material within 12 episodes. The biggest change from the light novel is that the anime

> neglects to reveal the true identity of the First Beast,

> but author Kareno probably retconned that spoiler from Volume 1 on purpose since it really didn't make sense to have that revelation so early. A certain beast is not introduced at all in the anime and this character is

> critical to Volumes 4 and 5.

> There's also little differences. For example, in World End Episode 11 the characters find a girl encased in crystal. [In the light novel...]

> Willem activates his "spell vision," an ability never used in the anime, to analyze the curse and the narrative gives more details about the hex's abilities. The book also has a long discussion between him and Grick about the state of the girl and whether it’s possible to resurrect her like what was done with Willem. When Chtholly becomes entranced by the crystal, Willem literally has to plunge his hand into her chest, collapsing her lungs, in order to disrupt her magic flow and return her to normal.

> That's just one minor scene, **which gives you an idea of how much content the anime skips over. As you can see, it's worth reading the light novels even if you've watched the anime**.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

---

Also, [the Japanese's impressions on episode 6 (= end of volume 2)](http://jumpmagazinetabare.seesaa.net/article/449986857.html) are more-or-less: those who have read the light novel were more emotionally moved than those who only watched the anime since the anime skipped a lot/the pace was too quick.

Comment: This agrees with what I remember from the novels. The ending of the anime is more-or-less unchanged from the end of the 3rd volume, but there are some minor to moderate changes including a few events from later being included in the anime and many cuts. Nothing is so drastically changed that it would cause problems adapting the remaining novels though.